# How to call copy constructor from inside operator constructor correctly?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, copy-constructor, function-call

My code can also be found [here](http://pastebin.com/xG3j1epw).

This code would work (but there is much code duplication):

```
Employee::Employee(const Employee& x)
{
        name=new char [strlen(x.name)+1];
        strcpy(name, x. name);
        strcpy(EGN, x.EGN);
        salary=x.salary;
}

void Employee::operator=(const Employee& x)
{
        delete[] name;
        name=new char [strlen(x.name)+1];
        strcpy(name, x. name);
        strcpy(EGN, x.EGN);
        salary=x.salary;
}

Employee::Employee(char* n, char* e, double s)
{
        name = new char [strlen(n)+1];
        strcpy(name, n);
        strcpy(EGN, e);
        salary=s;
}
```

Below is my attempt to avoid writing same thing three times... but it does not work. Isn't it possible to make that code shorter?

```
Employee::Employee(char* n, char* e, double s)
{
        name = new char [strlen(n)+1];
        strcpy(name, n);
        strcpy(EGN, e);
        salary=s;
}

Employee::Employee(const Employee& x)
{
        Employee(x.name, x.EGN, x.salary);
}

void Employee::operator=(const Employee& x)
{
        delete[] name;
        Employee(x);
}
```

Comment: Please add the code to your post instead of an external site.

Comment: Declare `name` as `std::string`, let compiler generate the Big Three for you and move on.

Comment: nope, it has to be char*

Comment: Your `operator=` is not exception safe. You should not alter any members until you have completed all operations that can throw (this includes call new). Currently your code does not even provide the `basic exception gurantees`. Loop up `Copy and Swap Idiom` for a resonable way of implementing `operator=`

Comment: Your `operator=` is not safe to self assign. `a = a;` will cause the name to be released and later create new memory and copy the uninitialized data. That is, after `a = a;` the value of `a` is random. [@LokiAstari: the assignment operator offers the *no-throw* guarantee, it will *never* throw]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot call a constructor as a member function. You can create a member function, and call it from the constructor, and from all the other places.

```
void Employee::Init(const char* n, const char* e, double s)
{
        name = new char [strlen(n)+1];
        strcpy(name, n);
        strcpy(EGN, e);
        salary=s;
}

void Employee::Init(const Employee &x)
{
        Init(x.name, x.EGN, x.salary);
}

Employee::Employee(char* n, char* e, double s)
{
    Init(n,e,s);
}


Employee::Employee(const Employee& x)
{
     Init(x);
}

void Employee::operator=(const Employee& x)
{
        delete[] name;
        Init(x);
}
```

Comment: Does C++11 not allow constructor chaining?

Comment: @Loki, the OP is not asking about constructor chaining, if I understood correctly he wants to call a constructor from various places in his class (specifically `operator=`). Did I get the question wrong? To answer you - of course it allows.

Comment: okay one more question - How would you make this work if EGN is char[10], not char*?

Comment: @John, why not use `std::string`?

Comment: did it with (char*)&EGN[0] as second parameter in init(const Employee& x)

Comment: You should fix the assignment operator. It does not provide even the "Basic exception guarantee".

Answer (score 6):

What you are attempting is not allowed by the language. However, C++11 allows [*delegating constructors*](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#delegating-ctor), so you could do something like this:

```
Employee::Employee(const Employee& x) : Employee(x.name, x.EGN, x.salary){}
```

Note that one constructor is called in the initialization list of the other.

Before C++11, an option would have been to have some kinf of initialization function called from all the constructors. However, this is semantically different because the function call performs assignment to member variables, not initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in C++11

```
Employee::Employee(char* n, char* e, double s)
{
        name = new char [strlen(n)+1];
        strcpy(name, n);
        strcpy(EGN, e);
        salary=s;
}

// Constructor chaining (delegation) like this.
Employee::Employee(const Employee& x)
    : Employee(x.name, x.EGN, x.salary)
{}


// Use copy and swap for the assignment operator:

// Common convention to return a reference to yourself to allow chaingin.
Employee& Employee::operator=(Employee x)   // Pass by value to get the copy.
{ 
    x.swap(*this);                          // Then swap members
    return *this;
}                                           // Destructor will then cleanup.
```